# Laravel Blade looping through products based on relationship values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am using Multiple Table Inheritance to assign attributes to different product types

products table
| product_id | category |
| -------- | -------------- |
| xxx-1    | food            |
| xxx-2   | food             |
| xxx-3   | drink            |

products_food table for ***food specific attributes***
| product_id | nutrition_group |
| -------- | -------------- |
| xxx-1    | fruit            |
| xxx-2   | snack            |

With a `product` relationship

```
public function products_food() {
    return $this->hasOne('ProductFood::class','product_id')
}
```

If I have all products being sent to my blade template with the variable `$products`, **how do I loop through every `$product` with a `nutritional_group` value of `fruit`?**

I tried
`@foreach ($products->products_nutrition->where('nutritional_group','fruit') as $product)` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to filter the collection with dot notation.

```php
$products->where('products_food.nutritional_group', 'fruit') as $product
```